# replace multiple strings in a file in python3

Tags: awk, sed, python

I have test file where i have some entries like below and i need to change `memberUid` to `nisNetgroupTriple` along with the names

```
$ cat testfile2
memberUid: tony
memberUid: jacob
memberUid: zenny
memberUid: helori
memberUid: honies
memberUid: hunter
```

However, i'm able to change the `memberUid` to `nisNetgroupTriple` with unix `sed` like `%s/memberUid/nisNetgroupTriple/g`  and the angain using `awk` like `awk '{print $1, "(-,"$2",)"}' testfile2` but this two way process and i'm this can be done more elegantly which i'm not getting now.

Desired Output:

```
nisNetgroupTriple: (-,tony,)
nisNetgroupTriple: (-,jacob,)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're asking. Can you rephrase that? Do you need to modify the file by any means? Are you suggesting that sed can't complete the **whole** job? What has python3 got to do with any of this?

Comment: @tink, sorry for making it not clear, i just need to process the `testfile2` file in a  Desired format which i mentioned in the question, sed of course will do it only thing i'm not getting it on the top of my head as of now. python is just the sake of alternative and way to good to know.

Comment: Do all lines of your input file start `memberUid:`?  If not, please show some other example lines, and their desired output.

Comment: @JigglyNaga, yes thats true..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -r 's/^memberUid: (.*)/nisNetgroupTriple: (-,\1,)/' testfile2 
nisNetgroupTriple: (-,tony,)
nisNetgroupTriple: (-,jacob,)
nisNetgroupTriple: (-,zenny,)
nisNetgroupTriple: (-,helori,)
nisNetgroupTriple: (-,honies,)
nisNetgroupTriple: (-,hunter,)
```

Using sed with search and replace and a capturing group `(.*)`.
In the replacement string we just construct your desired format, and the `\1` fills in what was captured in the parenthesis.

Comment: I'll try it , thnx tink. would appreciate little explanation though.

Comment: Done ... makes sense?

Comment: completely make sense :-) thnx dude.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked for an answer using Python3, here is one using Python regex:

```python
import re
f = open(testfile2).read()
re.sub(r'(memberUid)(\:\s)(\w+)',r'nisNetgroupTriple\2(-,\3,)',f)
```

#### Explanation:

- `re` is the Python's regex module providing `re.sub` method which replaces a pattern with another pattern in the provided string in the following manner:

  - `re.sub(r'original-pattern', r'replacement-pattern', inputString)`
- The brackets used in the pattern are used for capturing groups in the **original pattern**. E.g. in our case, we have captured 3 groups: `memberUid`, `:\s` and `\w+`. Then, we can reference back to these groups in our replacement pattern as `\1`, `\2`  and so on.

Comment: @ Shivams, thnx Dude , it works perfectly +1

Answer (score 0):

As the first part of each input line will always be replaced, the `sed` is redundant.  All you need is

```
awk '{print "nisNetgroupTriple: (-,"$2",)"}'
```